# Open search result in the same window

Tags: window, search

Say I run `ag` or `grep` via `M-x` and display a window with search results. Say I then use my enter key to open a result. How can I force emacs to open this result in the same window as the search results are currently displaying, rather than a different window?

Comment: Do you mean the same [window](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Window.html) instead of [buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Buffers.html)? Reusing the same buffer would overwrite the search results. See also the answers to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13583/15748) for further clarification.

Comment: good shout. Edited

Comment: Do you want to be able to pick between using the current or a different window, or do you only ever want the current window to be reused?

Comment: See related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/745694/3084001), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8309769/3084001) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19080/15748).

Comment: Ideally I am looking for the equivalent of pressing o vs Enter in Dired mode (e,g an easy way to pick one or the other)

Thanks for the links, will look through them over lunch!

Comment: @AbrahamP Note that the links are relevant since `grep-mode` is derived from `compilation-mode`.

Comment: @AbrahamP A cursory glance reveals that the `compilation-mode` (as @Tobias usefully elaborated) family is pretty keen on opening a new window, but `ag` is special in that it provides the boolean user option `ag-reuse-window`. So an `ag`-specific solution would be to write a command revolving around `(let ((ag-reuse-window t)) (call-interactively #'compile-goto-error))`.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work for all modes derived from `compilation-mode`:

```el
(defun my-compile-goto-error-same-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action
         '((display-buffer-reuse-window
            display-buffer-same-window)
           (inhibit-same-window . nil))))
    (call-interactively #'compile-goto-error)))

(defun my-compilation-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "o") #'my-compile-goto-error-same-window))

(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook #'my-compilation-mode-hook)
```

With this snippet added to your init file, pressing <kbd>o</kbd> in a `grep` buffer (or any buffer derived from `compilation-mode`) will open the location in the same window.